# Opposing cars pass each other?

Tags: grammar, phrases

[image]

Let's say this is my hometown's narrow road. Further, can I say:

> "My hometown's road should be widened, because everytime opposing vehicles **pass each other**, they are always having a hard time to manuever their way around due to snug space.

Is the bold letter(phrase) correct?, specifically, do opposing vehicles **pass each other?**

Comment: If you have a two-lane, two-way road, vehicles pass each other in opposite directions and should probably not be passing each other otherwise. Pass each other can mean: to go around the vehicle in front of you.

Comment: *Snug* is a strange choice of word when referring to a road.  It means something like "cozy" or maybe "fitting tightly around".  **Tight** space would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually.  The sentence is perfectly natural (well, almost -- *every time* should be two words) right up to "always having".

Suggested correction:

> My hometown's road should be widened.  Every time opposing vehicles pass each other, they have a hard time maneuvering their way around one another because there is not enough room.

And possibly (but not necessarily) simplified to:

> My hometown's road should be widened, since it's difficult for opposing vehicles to pass due to the lack of space.

Comment: You don't really need 'opposing'. On a narrow road, it is difficult for vehicles to pass each other. In any case, we tend to speak of 'vehicles passing in opposite directions'. 'Opposing vehicles' sounds like they are having an argument.

Comment: I agree that opposing vehicles is not really idiomatic for the meaning here.  However, pass each other can mean both in opposing directions and in the same direction. "passing in opposite directions" does solve the issue.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase this as: **"My hometown's road should be widened, coz' it's difficult for vehicles passing in the opposite direction due to lack of space.''**

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  If you check around, particularly in documents related to traffic engineering or police reports, you'll see the phrase "opposing vehicles" all over the place.  It's not in any way unusual or misleading.

Comment: @JohnArvin  How you choose to write this is up to you, but I suggest you do some research when evaluating different suggestions.  The phrase "opposing vehicles" is fairly standard.